# Split pandas dataframe by custom weeks

Tags: python, pandas

Im working with a large pandas dataframe of the following format:

```
In [15]: data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 2869438 entries, 2011-09-26 22:00:00.078000 to 2011-12-30 22:14:57.413000
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Symbol    2869438  non-null values
Price     2869438  non-null values
Vol       2869438  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(1)
```

I have been able to split this into conventional weeks using the following:

```
weeks = data.groupby(data.index.week)
weeks.groups.keys()
Out[19]: [39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52]
```

For this particular dataframe weeks are defined as `'Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri'`

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
weekmask = 'Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri'
bday = CustomBusinessDay(weekmask=weekmask)
weeks = data.groupby(bday)
```

This gives me groups that are TimeStamp indexed and not by week number.

This is probably not the best way to achieve this, can anyone offer alternative techniques?

UPDATE:

Here is the head and tail of the data set I'm using:

```
data.head()
                             Symbol Price   Vol
DateTime            
2011-09-26 22:00:00.078000   CLX11   81.48   1
2011-09-26 22:00:00.192000   CLX11   81.46   1
2011-09-26 22:00:00.343000   CLX11   81.47   1
2011-09-26 22:00:00.443000   CLX11   81.46   1
2011-09-26 22:00:00.443000   CLX11   81.45   4

data.tail()
                             Symbol Price   Vol
DateTime            
2011-12-30 22:14:40.877000   CLG12   99.05   1
2011-12-30 22:14:43.287000   CLG12   99.06   1
2011-12-30 22:14:55.165000   CLG12   99.04   1
2011-12-30 22:14:55.165000   CLG12   99.03   1
2011-12-30 22:14:57.413000   CLG12   99.06   3
```

All I simply want todo is cut this data into weeks and write it out to CSV files, I can already do this for conventional weeks (Mon-Sun) but I now want to cut into weeks that are defined as Sun-Fri.

Can anyone help with that? The use of `CustomBuisnessDay` may not be what I want although it does seem to fit the use case.

Comment: can you post a small example of your dataframe? Easier to work with that way.

Comment: I don't understand this question, is it that you want to access the group name (the week number) in some calculation?

Comment: @AndyHayden sorry for the delay, I've updated the question to provide some more clarity.